# Group representation preserving determinant is isomorphic to its dual

Tags: representation-theory

Let $\rho:G \hookrightarrow \textrm{GL}_2(\mathbb C)$ be a representation where $G \subset \textrm{SU}(2)$ a finite group and $\rho^*$ its dual representation.
I can't seem to understand the following:

> Since $\textrm{SU}(2) \subset \textrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)$, $\rho$ preserves the determinant - a non-degenerate skew-symmetric bilinear form - and this gives an isomorphism between $\rho$ and $\rho^*$.

Is this a known linear algebra fact? How can one justify it?

Comment: The important term here is "non-degenerate". A non-degenerate bilinear form $B$ on $V$ gives an isomorphism between $V$ and its dual by $v \mapsto B(v,-)$. You then have to understand why this isomorphism is equivariant when $B$ is preserved.

Comment: There are a bunch of ways to show this, but the most explicit is: if $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\in\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb C)$, then the matrix $\det(A)A^{-t}=\begin{pmatrix}d & -c&\\-b&a\end{pmatrix}$ is conjugate to $A$ by the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$. So if $\det(A) = 1$, then $A$ is conjugate to its inverse transpose. Thus $\rho$ is isomorphic to its dual. In general, for 2d reps, $\rho^*\otimes\det(\rho)\cong\rho$.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Great response! thanks.